# SELECT INTO INTEGER ARRAY

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to assign values in a table column (column type is integer) to integer array. Unfortunately I could not.

--TYPE--

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ABILITY_ID_ARRAY IS VARRAY(100) OF INTEGER
```

--DECLARE IN PROCEDURE

```
ABILITY_IDS ABILITY_ID_ARRAY;
```

--STATEMENT--

```
SELECT ABILITY_FK INTO ABILITY_IDS 
FROM T_EDUCATION_ABILITY_REL 
WHERE EDUCATION_FK = edu_id;
```

I received this error:

> [Error] ORA-00932 (16: 12): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER

Comment: what type ABILITY_FK and ABILITY_IDS - looks like one is a dtatetime and the other a number.  also check your where clause

Comment: ABILITY_FK is integer, ABILITY_IDS is integer array referenced TYPE ABILITY_ID_ARRAY

Comment: Why "ABILITY_ID_ARRAY" when it's a generic array of integers? (Apart from the 100 limit. Is there some business rule about a maximum of 100 Ability IDs, or did you just hit the syntax requirement and type in a number to get it to compile? If so, make it a nested table instead of a varray.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **BULK COLLECT** clause to store a resultset into a collection variable.
Please study the documentation of `SELECT INTO` statement:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345
[image]

> **into_clause** 
>   With this clause, the SELECT INTO statement retrieves one or more columns **from a single row** and stores them in either one or
>   more **scalar variables** or one record variable.

---

> **bulk_collect_into_clause**
>  With this clause, the SELECT INTO statement retrieves an entire result set and stores it in one or more
>   **collection variables**.

---

The PL/SQL statament should look like this in your case:

```
SELECT ABILITY_FK BULK COLLECT INTO ABILITY_IDS 
FROM T_EDUCATION_ABILITY_REL 
WHERE EDUCATION_FK = edu_id;
```